# Docebo X-Authorization parameter

Tags: api, rest, authorization

Hey guys I am trying to call Docebo's REST APIs and I am finding it hard to understand the method for it. Basically, Calling an API requires you to place an X-Authorization Parameter in the request header. The Docebo documentation on implementing this is just a paragraph that is very confusing to read. A similar question has been asked and answered here :

[Docebo - constructing authorisation header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27830342/docebo-constructing-authorisation-header)

I read the code but couldn't quite grasp the explanation as there was little and the code very difficult for me to understand. I have two questions-

1)What is the X-Authorization parameter?

2)How does one compute the X-Authorization parameter to add to the request header to make calls to the Docebo API?

Detailed explanation of how the code works would be great! Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2):

Hey I finally figured it out.

**What is the X-Authorization parameter?**

It is the parameter that has to be added to the header of the request. This header is used to authenticate the call to an API and the server first checks for this parameter to know whether the call is coming from a trusted source. This kind of requests that have a custom X- headers are called pre-flighted requests that require the sender to first send an HTTP OPTIONS request. The server responds with a list of allowed actions that can be performed. Only if the origin(of the sender) is allowed to have the specific header/Have access to the server resources, the request is actually executed.

**How does one compute the X-Authorization parameter to add to the request header to make calls to the Docebo API?**

It is as follows :
First take a look at the API documentation of Docebo for the specific API you want to call. It will have a list of parameters that the call requires. Then, you need to have the API keys from docebo handy since both of them are used in generating this X-Authorization parameter.Then proceed as follows :

1)Suppose you have n parameters that the call needs.Do the following :
SHA1 encoding of the following string between the brackets - (param-1,param-2,param-3.....param-n,secretKey).Don't forget the commas! Take the SHA1 hash generated in this step and proceed to step 2

2)A UTF-8 base64 encoding of the following string between the brackets- 
(PublicKey:hash from step 1).Again, don't forget the colon! and you will obtain an alphanumeric string.

3) The X-Authorization parameter is - Docebo code(notice the space between Docebo and the code).

4)Add the parameter named X-Authorization to the request header before sending it and you will receive the response.

Hope this helps..